# How both and each differ?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

> 1. Attach a connector to each end of each cable.
> 2. Attach a connector to both ends of each cable.

I am not sure the 2nd sentence above I created is grammatically correct.

I think it should be corrected to **"Attach (two) connectors to both ends of each cable"**, because "ends" is plural.  But, in such a case, it may be unclear how many connectors are attached to each end.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest (with little surety) that in this context "both" implies an action that is applied to two things, whereas "each" implies an action applied one time for every end of the cable.

That is, the first would use two connectors, and the second would use one connector (attached to the two ends).

However, this is English, so it can mean anything you want if you use it that way for long enough with enough people. :-)

Answer (score -2):

The general rule is:

- Both = exactly 2 of something
- Each = 2 or more of something

So in your example, since a cable has exactly 2 ends, "both" is appropriate.